# Python - Bland-Altman Plot with Text Customization

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, statsmodels

I am trying to Create the Bland-Altman Plot with the text having on the left side of the plot instead of having it as the default configuration on the right hand side

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9,
                         10, 11, 13, 14, 14, 15, 18, 22, 25],
                   'B': [4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 7, 8, 6, 9, 7, 7, 11,
                         13, 13, 12, 13, 14, 19, 19, 24]})

import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#create Bland-Altman plot                  
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize = (8,5))
sm.graphics.mean_diff_plot(df.A, df.B, ax = ax)

#display Bland-Altman plot
plt.show()
```

So I want to have the "mean", the "SD+" and the "SD-" on the left side of the X-axis, not on the right.

thanks for your help or any suggestions!

Comment: can u please provide an example of `df`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but I can use pyplot so:

```
mean_diff = (df.A-df.B).mean()
diff_range = (df.A-df.B).std()*1.96

plt.figure(figsize = (9,6))

plt.scatter(df.A, df.A-df.B, alpha=.5)

plt.hlines(mean_diff, df.A.min()-2, df.A.max()+2, color="k", linewidth=1)
plt.text(
    df.A.min()-1, mean_diff+.05*diff_range, "mean diff: %.2f"%mean_diff,
    fontsize=13, 
)

plt.hlines(
    [mean_diff+diff_range, mean_diff-diff_range],
    df.A.min()-2, df.A.max()+2, color="k", linewidth=1,
    linestyle="--"
)
plt.text(
    df.A.min()-1, mean_diff+diff_range+.05*diff_range, 
    "+SD1.96: %.2f"%(mean_diff+diff_range),
    fontsize=13, 
)
plt.text(
    df.A.min()-1, mean_diff-diff_range+.05*diff_range, 
    "-SD1.96: %.2f"%(mean_diff-diff_range),
    fontsize=13, 
)

plt.xlim(df.A.min()-2, df.A.max()+2)
plt.ylim(mean_diff-diff_range*1.5, mean_diff+diff_range*1.5)
plt.xlabel("Means", fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel("Difference", fontsize=15)

plt.show()
```

result:

[image]